# different ways to access associated tables

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, data-retrieval

after i get the query result , i have problem accessing the associated tables that i joined in my table class
debug($query) :

```
    src\Model\Table\ComlibsTable.php (line 30)
       [
       (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Comlib) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'question' => 'how to kill someone?',
    'answer' => (int) 2,
    'asked' => (int) 90,
    'tags' => 'kill,proffesional killer',
    'created' => null,
    'modified' => null,
    'answers' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'the crackpot will attack the will of the darkness and then i starve',
            'rate' => (float) 11.2,
            'view' => (int) 22,
            'helpful' => '11|22',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Comlibs'

}
]
```

now i know i can access Comlib entity like : $query[0]['question']; 
but i wonder is there another way to access the entities like $query->question;
and how i can access the answers entity ,
my controller code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class ComlibsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

    }

    public function getResult(){

        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('comlib');
        $live_req = $this->request->data['searchBox'];
        $query = $this->Comlibs->LFM($live_req);

        $this->set('question',$query[0]['question']); // does work
        $this->set('answer',$query['answers'][0]['id']); // does not work

    }
}
```

LFM function

```
public function LFM( $live_req) {

$query = $this->find()->where(['question' => $live_req])->contain(['Answers']);
$query = $query->toArray();
debug($query);
//include 5 answer
return $query;

    }
}
```

tnx for any help

Comment: show your model associations and your Comlibs->LFM function

Comment: what do you mean by model associatons ? if you mean answer entity there is nothing in it just the cake php structure for a entity without any function in it , Comlib model has an initialize function in the model. thats it

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out after trying different ways , since it was an array all i had to do was to access the array in the right way and that was :

```
$this->set('answer',$query[0]['answers'][0]['id']);
```

now i can access the values , but it seems like this is not the right way to access an array property , is there another way ? HOW can i remove the [0] from $query[0] ?